# Convert from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

i need convertfrom vb6 to vb.net

```
(picturebox1.TextWidth(RsSearch.Fields(Fs.FieldName)) / 2)
```

also from vb6 to vb.net

```
picturebox1.Line (x, y) - ((Width +x) / Reducer, (y+ Height) / Reducer), Fs.LineColor
```

also from vb6 to vb.net

```
picturebox1.DrawWidth = Int(Fs.LineWidth / 2)
```

also what mean in vb.net for proprety hdc in picturebox like
picturebox1.hdc

Comment: We do not convert code here we help fix programming issues not translate code. Please repost what you have done and why its not working.

Answer (score 1):

In vb.net you can use the Graphics class for these drawing functions, either on the picturebox control in the Paint event, or on the picturebox's image for persistant graphics. For example, to draw a line:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
  e.Graphics.DrawLine...
End Sub
```

or

```
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
  g.DrawLine...
```